# 2-column design with main content containing boxes that I need to align in a 2 column layout

Tags: css, fluid-layout

Here's an example of my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ECkE/1/

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                test
            </li>
            <li>
                test
            </li>
            <li>
                test
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
        <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
        <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.box{float:left; padding:20px; border:1px solid red;}
.three{clear:left;}
.sidebar{float:left;}
```

I have tried adding float:left to .content{} however, that only works when the screen is wide, for mobile displays the full content area ends up going below the sidebar. If I try using span7 (bootstrap, width: 58%), then it doesn't work for wide screen.

Is there another way I can set the arrangement without needing to set the width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having with float is due to the height of your first left float. There is enough height on the left float to prevent box 1 and 2 from falling below it but not box 3. There are two ways to prevent this. You can add artificial height to .sidebar with height: 300px; or something like that. Or you can use a more common practice and use left and right floats. So your .sidebar would be float: left; and your .content would be float: right;. If you choose to go with different floats you should declare the width for each say .sidebar would have a width: 30%; and .content would have a width: 70%;. You can play around with the percentages for the widths they are there to help format the page style. If you use borders you will have to change the percentages to accommodate them.

Comment: Well that's what's strange is that I have both sidebar and content as the same height in my actual code (via Javascript to set both to same height). However, testing with float:left for sidebar and float:right for content with set widths works better than my previous attempts, so I'll go with that :)

Answer (score 1):

Clear your `content` **class**

as like this

```
.content{overflow:hidden;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/9ECkE/4/)**

### -------------------------

**Option two**

and define your `content` **class**

```
float left
```

as like this

```
.content{float:left;}
```

Comment: Hmm, overflow-x: hidden; gives a better result. Though not quite 100%, I think I need to redesign the way I do my sidebar and content, since the sidebar collapses' at a certain width (i.e. for tablets/mobile). Will accept this answer as I don't think there's a better way from my example code.